# Unix_TIMESTAMP for hive not working in Shell Script

Tags: shell, hive, hiveql

I am Running a hive Query

`hive -hiveconf prvDate=$prvDate -S -e "select max(ID) from Employee where unix_timestamp(date,'dd-MM-yyyy') > unix_timestamp('${hiveconf:prvDate}','dd-MM-yyyy')"`

It is returning NULL. prvdate is `15-12-2017`

but when I running the same script in Hive

```
select max(ID) from Employee where unix_timestamp(date,'dd-MM-yyyy') > unix_timestamp('15-12-2017','dd-MM-yyyy')
```

I am able to see the Result. Can someone help?

Comment: read this: http://community.cloudera.com/t5/Batch-SQL-Apache-Hive/Passing-parameters-in-Hive/td-p/45622

Comment: you should be using ${hiveconf:val}  instead of prvDate, isn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you are running hive with inline SQL inside shell script you do not need to pass -hiveconf variable, use shell substitution instead.

Example (shell):

```
prvDate="01-01-2017"

hive -S -e "select unix_timestamp('$prvDate','dd-MM-yyyy')"
```

Output:
1483257600

Use --hiveconf only if you are executing SQL script file:

```
hive --hiveconf bla="$bla" -f myscript.hql
```

Answer (score 0):

it is because you are calling your hiveconf var, change the name and it should work

```
hive -hiveconf prvDate=$prvDate -S -e "select max(ID) from Employee where unix_timestamp(date,'dd-MM-yyyy') > unix_timestamp('${hiveconf:prvDate}','dd-MM-yyyy')"
```

Comment: Sorry there was a typo I have prvDate instead of Val.